# Python tkinter: How can I programmatically show Labels with text at specific positions in the window?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

How to display tkinter Labels with text at certain intervals in the window?

```
pos = label.winfo_height()//2 - 250
y = 0
for k in range(0, KET1):
    if k > 0:
        pos = pos + 4*y
    exec(f'Label{k}=tk.Label(window,text="{k+1}){DES1[k]}")\nLabel{k}.place(x=label.winfo_width() + 250, y=pos)')
    exec(f"y=Label{k}.winfo_height()")
    #window.update()
    #window.after(10)

window.mainloop()
```

If you execute this code in debug mode, the result is like this:[DEBUG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBrfK.png)
If you execute this code in normak mode:[ACTUALLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5guc.png)

Comment: It seems like you have used a debugger in an IDE made from `tkinter`, so the widget are created and initialized before executing `.winfo_height()` so it gets correct value.  However when running in normal mode, the tkinter `mainloop()` does not take control when the for loop is being executed, so the widget is not properly initialized and `.winfo_height()` will not return correct value.

Comment: What can you advise to do?

Comment: Call `window.update()` between the two `exec()`.  Also it is not recommended (actually not necessary) to use `exec()` in your case.

Comment: How do I create new Labels without exec, can you please tell me? )

Comment: Just calling `lbl = tk.Label(...)`, `lbl = place(...)` and `y = lbl.winfo_height()`.